# Different links to different bootstrap carousel slides in one page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have found a perfectly working solution to the question of how to link to a specific slide in a bootstrap carousel. However, I have multiple carousels with different Id's running on the same page. How can my link target a specific carousel id?

The specifics:
I have three carousels
They have different ids: "carousel-01", "carousel-02", "carousel-03".

I call the function to be able to link to specific slides. Here it is carousel-01. Could also be carousel-03

```
function goToSlide(number) {$("#carousel-01").carousel(number);}
```

Then I put my link in the markup

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:goToSlide(2);">Go to slide #5</a>
```

My question is: How can I make the link target a carousel with a specific id. Let's say, I'd want not #carousel-01 move but #carousel-03?

Answer (score 2):

You must use different id for both carousel like this

```
<!--carousel one -->

    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        ...
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div><!--end of carousel one -->

<!--carousel two -->

    <div id="carousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        ...
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel2" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div><!--end of carousel two -->
```

Then call the carousel via javascript

```
   <script>
         //for carousel one
         $('#carousel').carousel()
         //for carousel two
         $('#carousel2').carousel()

    </script>
```

Comment: I have done that, but how can I get only carousel2 to slide when I click on the link I created?

Comment: I hope my below code helped you out...Please check the updated code below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for that on click if 'Go to slide3' , It will take the specific slider , ex: that is now i am targeting it to the class 'slidehere' in '#carousel2'

```
    <!-- link to specific slider -->
    <a href="#" class="slide3">Go to slide3</a>

        <!--carousel one -->

    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        ...
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div><!--end of carousel one -->

<!--carousel two -->

    <div id="carousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel2" data-slide-to="2" class="slidethis"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item slidethis">  <!-- targeted item on click 'slidethis'-->
          <img src="..." alt="...">
          <p>slide</p>
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
        ...
      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel2" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div><!--end of carousel two -->
```

javascript required

```
 <script>

         //for carousel one
         $('#carousel').carousel()
         //for carousel two

         $('.slide3').click(function() { //onclick

            /* Act on the event */

            $('#carousel2 .carousel-inner .slidethis').siblings().removeClass('active');//removes active class from siblings
            $('#carousel2 .carousel-inner .slidethis').addClass('active') //adding active class to targeted slide
            $('#carousel2 .carousel-indicators .slidethis').siblings().removeClass('active');//removes active class from siblings
          $('#carousel2 .carousel-indicators .slidethis').addClass('active')/adding active class to targeted slide

         });
        </script>
```